# QGraphicsScene mouseMoveEvent does not work until QGraphicsView wheelEvent

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview, qgraphicsscene

I have a strange issue that I have been unable to determine the cause. Basically, I created a 2D view with pan and zoom functionality and a scene with items that can moved with grid snapping. To move an item in the scene I extended `Scene::mousePressEvent` to get a pointer to the item and `Scene::mouseMoveEvent` to keep the item tracked on the cursor. To drop the item, I used `Scene::mousePressEvent` again. To pan, I extended `View::mousePressEvent`, `View::mouseReleaseEvent`, and `View::mouseMoveEvent` and to zoom I extended `View::wheelEvent`.

**Now for the symptoms:**

I start the application with an item in the Scene. If I click and hold, then move the mouse, the item moves as intended. As soon as I release the mouse button, the item stops moving. I can click to drop and the item is placed according to the drop code in `Scene::mousePressEvent`. Try again and still the item only moves when the mouse button is pressed.

**Then comes the strange part:** If I use the mouse wheel to zoom the View, everything performs as expected after that event. The mouse is clicked to select an item, it moves as I move the mouse and drops when I click again.

So the obvious solution:

```
    wheelEvent(new QWheelEvent(QPointF(0,0),0,Qt::NoButton,Qt::NoModifier));
```

called at the creation of the View and everything works fine. It calls the extended `View::wheelEvent` with no change to the view and before the scene is even created, but afterwards the programs behaves as expected.

So I'm here to see if any of the excellent Qt experts out there can explain this strange behavior. Any comments or direction are appreciated.

In case it helps, here is the `View::wheelEvent` override code. `tform` is a `QTransform` with which I maintain zoom. Also, I've tried with and without the call to the base method but there is no change in behavior.

```cpp
void SchematicView::wheelEvent(QWheelEvent* event)
{  
    // Scale the view / do the zoom
    double scaleFactor = 1.1;

    if(event->delta() > 0 && tform.m11() < max_zoom) {
        tform.scale(scaleFactor,scaleFactor);
    } else if (event->delta() < 0 && tform.m11() > min_zoom){
        tform.scale(1.0/scaleFactor,1.0/scaleFactor);
    }

    setTransformationAnchor(QGraphicsView::AnchorUnderMouse);
    setTransform(tform);

    QGraphicsView::wheelEvent(event);

}
```

Comment: Note that your obvious solution is leaking the QWheelEvent object... you'd be better off placing the QWheelEvent object on the stack, or at least deleting it after wheelEvent() returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without a [SSCCE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions) to look at and test with, it's hard to say for sure, but what you're describing sounds a lot like your mouseMoveEvent() callback is only getting called when the mouse button is being held down during the move.  That, in turn, sounds a lot like the expected behavior for mouseMoveEvent(), as documented in [QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseMoveEvent):

> If mouse tracking is switched off, mouse move events only occur if a
>   mouse button is pressed while the mouse is being moved. If mouse
>   tracking is switched on, mouse move events occur even if no mouse
>   button is pressed.

If that is indeed the problem, then a call to [setMouseTracking(true)](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#mouseTracking-prop) may get you the behavior you are looking for.

On a broader level, note that there are easier ways of obtaining the behavior you are trying to implement -- for example, to allow the user to drag and drop items in a QGraphicsScene, all you really have to do is call setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable) on any QGraphicsItems that you want the user to be able to drag around.  No hand-coding of event handlers is necessary unless you are trying to obtain some non-standard behaviors.

Comment: I think you're on to something with setMouseTracking(true). I'll try it tomorrow. As for the scene coding, I need to snap to grid so I have to handle the pressEvent. I appreciate the suggestion on ItemIsMovable but I've created my own Item classes that represent different shapes and pixmaps, and since I had to override the virtual paint event, I haven't noticed the flags doing anything. If you have any suggestions for using a custom Item class with default movable behavior that I can snap to grid, I'd be very happy to hear it. No reason to reinvent the wheel. No pun intended.

Comment: I believe the standard item-move functionality can be made to work with custom QGraphicsItem subclasses (I haven't tried it myself, but I'd be surprised if it wasn't possible).  As for snap-to-grid, I think the way to implement that would be to override the itemChange(GraphicsItemChange change, const QVariant & value) method in your QGraphicsItem subclass and in the case where (change) is equal to ItemPositionChange return the snapped-to-grid position for the item.  (see the note here:  http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qgraphicsitem.html#GraphicsItemChange-enum )

Comment: Thank you for the solution to the mouse tracking issue. I feel dumb for having asked because I did search the docs before coming here and did not understand how the wheelEvent was related to the mouseMove.

Comment: Don't feel bad, I don't understand how the wheelEvent is related either :)

Comment: If I'd known about `setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable) ` before I wasted a day implementing with events I would have been a lot more happy